# Is there a simple way to achieve the effect of `--no-parent` and also grab files from a specific top level directory, with wget?

Tags: wget

Using `wget` version `1.20.3` or higher...

I am currently using a command like so, to keep a static "backup" of my blog, but only pages under "/blog":

`wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --wait=1 https://example.com/blog`

*However*, some of my blog pages reference static downloadable files (usually a PDF; so extensions are known and predictable) that are stored in a top-level "static" directory, e.g.,

`https://example.com/static-files/file1.pdf` or `https://example.com/static-files/file2.png`

I would like the behavior of `--no-parent`, where only pages under `/blog` are downloaded, but I would also *specifically* like to archive all files that are linked to, that exist in the `static-files` directory.

### Is there a simple way to do that with a single wget command?

If not, is there a reasonable compromise?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this will do what I need (it definitely downloaded the static files). Tho it seemed to download slightly different sets of files, so I'm not 100% sure what might be different:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --wait=1  --include-directories="/s,/blog" https://example.com/blog/
```

The output directories I have now are `blog` and `static-files`. `blog` contains more than it did... but I haven't looked at why.

The main difference here is that instead of excluding parent directories, we're  *only* including the directories we want content from.

I welcome anyone to expound on the differences, and explain why this may or may not be the correct answer.